# collection_select: TypeError: ["foo","bar","baz"] is not a symbol nor a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `Imagecapturing` table with column `city`. I want to implement a search form select dropdown list of cities.

In my view, I have a form that should display a dropdown list with cities:

```
<%= form_tag imagecapturings_path, method: :get do %>
   <%= collection_select(nil, :imagecapturing_id, Imagecapturing.all, :ort, Imagecapturing.cities, prompt: false) %>
   <%= submit_tag("Search", :name=>"submit") %>
<% end %>
```

In model/imagecapturing.rb:

```
  def self.cities
    Imagecapturing.distinct.pluck(:city).sort!
  end
```

In my browser, I get the error message: `TypeError in Imagecapturings#index
["foo","bar","baz"] is not a symbol nor a string`.

How can I fix the `collection_select` method call?

Comment: What is `collection_select`?

Comment: @sawa i believe it is coming from https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Thanks.

Comment: @Trinity76 Following JagdeepSingh's link tells that the parameter `text_method` to `collection_select` should be a method name. But you are passing an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're passing `nil` as the first arg to `collection_select`, it looks to me as if you should be using a `select_tag`. This would need to be updated as follows:

```
<%= form_tag imagecapturings_path, method: :get do %>
   <%= select_tag :imagecapturing_id, options_from_collection_for_select(
     Imagecapturing.all, :ort, :city_name, prompt: false # plus any other desired options
   ) %>
   <%= submit_tag("Search", :name=>"submit") %>
<% end %>
```

As far as I can tell, [`collection_select`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) is designed for use with a form object, while [`select_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) operates without one, as in your use case.

[`options_from_collection_for_select`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) then takes the options in a similar manner to as you have specified - although, as Ajith has pointed out, the arguments should be a collection, followed by two methods that work on this collection.

The first `:ort` is the select option's value (more typically an `id`), the second `:city_name`, its display name. As in their answer, you'll need to ensure there's a method `city_name` available for `imaginecapturing` instances.

The method then returns a string of option tags, that would appear like the following:

```
'<option value="#{ort}">#{city_name}</option>....and so on'
```

This last part is where the error lies, and reworking your code to look like the above should resolve your issue.

Comment: Try this @Trinity76: `Imagecapturing.joins(:city).uniq(&:city)` - that should return only `imagecapturings` with unique city names. If that's not what you're after, I'd say that's perfect fodder for a new question :) Happy to have helped - let me know how you get on with that or feel free to @ me on the new question if needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= collection_select(nil, :imagecapturing_id, Imagecapturing.all, :ort, Imagecapturing.cities, prompt: false) %>
```

in the above line Imagecapturing.cities returns an array. it expects a string or symbol. in simple word it is expecting the text value that need to be displayed for each option.

see this code

```
<%= form_tag charges_path, method: :get do %>
   <%= collection_select(nil, :id, ImageCapturing.all, :id, :city_name, prompt: false) %>
   <%= submit_tag("Search", :name=>"submit") %>
<% end %>
```

and my model is

```
class ImageCapturing < ApplicationRecord

    def city_name
        self.city
    end
end
```

Modify the id's accordingly.

Thanks,
Ajith

Comment: How can I prevent to get the same city more than once? With your solution I get "foo" multiple times. By the way that's the reason why I wrote Imagecapturing.distinct.pluck(:city).sort! but unfortunately it didn't worked in combination with collection_sort.

Comment: ImageCapturing.all isn't this uniq?? This is the collection you are trying to render inside the options

Comment: yes, the table Imagecapturing has multiple records with same attribute city for example {id: 1, name: foo, harddisk_id: 1, city: foo}, {id: 2, name: bar, harddisk_id: 3, city: foo},{id: 3, name: baz, harddisk_id: 4, city: foo}

Comment: ImageCapturing.select('distinct(city)') something like this will give distinct city.

Comment: then I get "private method `select' called for #<Imagecapturing:0x007faa674c8c90>"

Comment: def self.cities
     ImageCapturing.select("distinct city")
end

and use it like this <%= collection_select(nil, :id, ImageCapturing.cities, :id, :city_name, prompt: false) %>